# Using micros() to measure analogRead() time varies based on Serial.print location?

Tags: serial, analogread, adc, array

I'm trying to use micros() to measure the time it takes to execute an analogRead() cycle, but am having some issues.  Originally, I just printed out the measured time for the analogRead() right after doing the subtraction, but I wanted to change that to printing out all of the time values for the 100 loops at once.  When I print the start times, end times, and values both in the if statement (right after calculating them) and at the end, the values printed are the same.  I'm not sure if they're accurate because they fluctuate a lot within those 100 tests.  For example, some of these measured times consecutively are 216, 97, 153, 34, 89, 145, 27.  I put the ADC in freerun mode, so I figured it could be normal for that.  However, when I don't print the start times, end times, or values immediately after calculating them and instead try to print them in the else if statement, it gives a stream of values that are all either 407 or 408.  If I print "Test" instead of the values right after calculating them, it still gives the (I'm assuming) correct values that vary a lot, not the 407s.  If, instead of printing them in the if statement, I print them just in the general loop (currently commented out) and the else if statement, they are still the varying maybe-correct values.  I assumed that even if the values aren't being printed, they're still being stored in the array correctly.  I don't understand why printing something unrelated right after storing the values would change them.  Any ideas?

Thanks

```
    int sensorPin = A1;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
    int ledPin = 13;      // select the pin for the LED
    int sensorValue[1000];  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
    int ind = 0;
    int starts[1000];
    int ends[1000];
    int vals[1000];
    int stopprint = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int countto = 100;

    void setup() {
      // declare the ledPin as an OUTPUT:
      Serial.begin(57600);
      analogReadResolution(12);
      pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
      Serial.println("ready to begin");
        analogReadSetup(A1);
      for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        starts[i] = 0;
        ends[i] = 0;
        vals[i] = 0;
      }
    }

    void loop() {
      // read the value from the sensor:
      if (ind < countto) {
      starts[ind] = micros();
    //  delay(50);
      sensorValue[ind] = analogRead(sensorPin);
      ends[ind] = micros();
      vals[ind] = ends[ind] - starts[ind];
    //  Serial.println("Test");
        Serial.print(ind);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(starts[ind]);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(ends[ind]);
        Serial.print('\t');   
        Serial.print(vals[ind]);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print('|');
        Serial.print('\t');
      Serial.print('\n');
      Serial.print('\r');
      ind++;
      }
      else if (stopprint == 0) {
        Serial.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        for (int j = 0; j < countto; j++) {
    //        Serial.println(j);
            Serial.print(starts[j]);
            Serial.print('\t');
            Serial.print(ends[j]);
            Serial.print('\t');
            Serial.print(vals[j]);
            Serial.print('\n');
            Serial.print('\r');
            stopprint = 1;
        }
      }
      else if (stopprint == 1) {
        while(1);
      }
    //  Serial.print(ind-1);
    //  Serial.print('\t');
    //  Serial.print(starts[ind-1]);
    //  Serial.print('\t');
    //  Serial.print(ends[ind-1]);
    //  Serial.print('\t');
    //  Serial.print(vals[ind-1]);
    //  Serial.print('\n');
    //  Serial.print('\r');
   }
```

Also, I'm using the Arduino Zero if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is related to your problem but... if I were to try such a
measurement, I would use local variables, like

```c++
unsigned int start = micros();
int value = analogRead(sensorPin);
unsigned int end = micros();
sensorValue[ind] = value;
starts[ind] = start;
ends[ind] = end;
vals[ind] = end - start;
```

This way you would be measuring the time it takes to call both
`analogRead()` and `micros()`, and very little more. If you do something
like

```c++
sensorValue[ind] = analogRead(sensorPin);
```

then you are also measuring the time taken by the pointer arithmetic and
the memory access.

I generally program AVR-based Arduinos. These have a load-store
architecture, where saving to a local variable costs essentially
nothing, as the variable is typically assigned a CPU register by the
compiler. Saving to a global takes more time because of the RAM access.

I have no experience with ARM-based Arduinos, like the Zero, but I
believe it's also a load-store architecture, thus the same
considerations should probably apply.

**Update**: I tried the following experiment on my Uno:

```c++
#define PRINT_WHILE_READING

#define READ_COUNT 100

void setup() {
    unsigned int starts[READ_COUNT];
    unsigned int ends[READ_COUNT];
    unsigned int vals[READ_COUNT];

    Serial.begin(57600);
    Serial.println("Ready to begin");

    // Take the readings.
    for (int i = 0; i < READ_COUNT; i++) {
        starts[i] = micros();
        analogRead(A1);
        ends[i] = micros();
        vals[i] = ends[i] - starts[i];
#if defined(PRINT_WHILE_READING)
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(starts[i]);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(ends[i]);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.println(vals[i]);
#endif
    }

#if !defined(PRINT_WHILE_READING)
    // Print them now.
    Serial.println("All data taken");
    for (int i = 0; i < READ_COUNT; i++) {
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(starts[i]);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print(ends[i]);
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.println(vals[i]);
    }
#endif
}

void loop() {}
```

If `PRINT_WHILE_READING` is defined as above, I get times that fluctuate
between 108 and 116 µs. If I comment out the line
`#define PRINT_WHILE_READING`, I get mostly 116 µs and,
occasionally, 124 µs. In both cases, the first reading takes longer
(208 and 212 µs respectively).

The fact that the first reading takes longer is explained in the
datasheet: the ADC does some initializations in that first reading. All
measured times are multiples of 4 µs because that is the resolution
of `micros()`.

Now, trying to understand the differences between the two cases:

1. With `PRINT_WHILE_READING` the times are shorter on average. This is
   because the numbers are not stored in RAM, as the compiler figured
   out the arrays `starts[]`, `ends[]` and `vals[]` are not really
   needed and optimized them away. When `PRINT_WHILE_READING` is not
   defined, I can see the “store in RAM” instructions in the generated
   assembly.
2. With `PRINT_WHILE_READING` the numbers fluctuate more. I guess this
   is due to the printing through the serial port taking a variable
   amount of time depending on the numbers being printed, and thus
   creating timing inconsistencies.

The last point deserves some explanation. The ADC is clocked by a
prescaler that divides the frequency of the main clock by 128. This
gives a clock period of 8 µs. When an ADC conversion is started,
the ADC waits for the next rising edge of its clock, which can take
anywhere between 0 and 8 µs, then it does the conversion in
13 cycles of its clock. This means the whole process can take
anywhere between 104 and 112 µs depending on the exact time the
conversion is started relative to the phase of the prescaler. If the
conversions are started at irregular intervals, you expect to see
roughly 8 µs of fluctuation in the measured times.

All these observations have been done on an Uno, which is based on an
AVR clocked at 16 MHz. I know the Zero is quite different. You will
have to look at the datasheet of the ATSAMD21G18 to see whether anything
of the above can be extrapolated to the Zero.

Comment: I tried changing it to your format and nothing changed.  Thanks for the idea though.  If you have any more ideas about what could be causing it I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: If you understand ARM assembly, you could disassemble the program to see the code generated by the compiler. That's what I would do on an AVR to try to understand that kind of issue, but I cannot read ARM assembly.

Comment: That's more or less what I've been doing for about an hour now, but I haven't really found anything that would explain it

Comment: @Alexandra: I've updated the answer with some experiments done on my Uno. Maybe some of these results could be extrapolated to the Zero.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm now just trying to get the time down from what the analogRead() timing is.  The datasheet says it should take ~100 microseconds per read (on the Arduino Zero at least which I'm using), but by driving pins high to measure it, it's still taking about 400 microseconds.  I've put the ADC in freerun mode and tried changing the prescaler but it doesn't even get close to 100 microseconds.  I saw posts of people trying to get it below 100 us previously, but I'm not even reaching that baseline and I'm not sure why.  Any ideas? (also posted on other comment, sorry)

Comment: @Alexandra: No idea, sorry. I think at this point only someone with good knowledge of that particular chip could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a digital scope, try bracketing your code with changes to the state of an output pin. print() has a lot of moving parts, some (like buffer size, interrupt implementation) will vary with various Arduinos as others have noted. I am mostly using ARM Cortex M4 on Teensy 3.2. If I want to time something really precisely I will drive an I/O pin (with digitalWrite()) at the beginning and end of what I want to time. This has super fast execution. You could use more than one pin to see two things at once. Then, look at them on an oscilloscope. Trigger on the starting edge of the most important signal. Adjust the time scale to encompass the active pin level time. With a digital scope you can set persistence to infinite and then you can see the variation on the trailing edge of the pulse. You can move the digitalWrite points around in your program until you see what is causing the variation. millis() and micros() are 32-bit values so on an 8-bit AVR that is multiple machine cycles to access. A single digitWrite is usually one machine cycle so it is quick even on a slowly-clocked 8-bit AVR. Once you find the place where most of the variation occurs you at least have a quantified smoking gun to tell you what details to excavate further.

Comment: A call to `digitalWrite()` on an AVR takes anywhere from 78 to 108 cycles, depending on the pin number and the value written. That's why, for time-critical tasks, people resort to [direct port access](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation): something like `PORTB |= _BV(5)` compiles into a single machine instruction and executes in two cycles.

Comment: On the other hand, for precise timing, you can set the 16-bit timer to run at `F_CPU` and read it directly, which only takes 4 cycles. If you want to be accurate to the cycle, you will have to look at the generated assembly to see what exactly you have between the timer reads.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm now just trying to get the time down from what the analogRead() timing is.  The datasheet says it should take ~100 microseconds per read (on the Arduino Zero at least which I'm using), but by driving pins high to measure it, it's still taking about 400 microseconds.  I've put the ADC in freerun mode and tried changing the prescaler but it doesn't even get close to 100 microseconds.  I saw posts of people trying to get it below 100 us previously, but I'm not even reaching that baseline and I'm not sure why.  Any ideas?